# Duda con el bucle for en combate rpg en python

Tags: python, bucle-for

¿Como hacer que cuando mi pokemon muere en el bucle for entonces no saliera el mensaje de escoja su pokemon cada vez que un pokemon muera?, habria alguna forma de que una vez de que muera el pokemon, que no vuelva a entrar en el if?

```
pokemon_escogido = input ('Escoja un pokemon: ')

for PokemonEnemigo in numero_pokemon_enemigo:

    if pokemon_escogido == 'Venasaur':
        combate(venasaur, PokemonEnemigo)
    elif pokemon_escogido == 'Charizard':
        combate(charizard,  PokemonEnemigo)
    elif pokemon_escogido == 'Blastoise':
        combate(blastoise, PokemonEnemigo)
    elif pokemon_escogido == 'Pidgeot':
        combate(pidgeot, PokemonEnemigo)
    elif pokemon_escogido == 'Arbok':
        combate(arbok, PokemonEnemigo)
    elif pokemon_escogido == 'Raichu':
        combate(raichu, PokemonEnemigo)
```

(si pongo todo el codigo, la pagina me dice que tiene demasiado codigo)  Quisiera saber si en el proximo if, podria hacer de alguna forma, que una vez que muera el pokemon o su hp llegue a 0, que entre en el if, solo 1 vez por pokemon, porque el problema que tengo es que cuando eligo otro pokemon, entra si o si en el if, porque ya tengo un pokemon muerto, y entonces, siempre acaba entrando y ejecutando ese input

```
    if charizard.hp <= 0 or venasaur.hp <= 0 or blastoise.hp <= 0 or pidgeot.hp 
       <= 0 or arbok.hp <= 0 or raichu.hp <= 0:

        print('\nEse pokemon esta debilitado')
        pokemon_escogido = input('\nEscoja otro pokemon: ')

        print('\n\n********** COMBATE **********\n\n')
        
        if PokemonEnemigo == venasaur2:
            print(pokemon_escogido + ' VS ' + venasaur2.nombre)
        elif PokemonEnemigo == charizard2:
            print(pokemon_escogido + ' VS ' + charizard2.nombre)
        elif PokemonEnemigo == blastoise2:
            print(pokemon_escogido + ' VS ' + blastoise2.nombre)
        elif PokemonEnemigo == pidgeot2:
            print(pokemon_escogido + ' VS ' + pidgeot2.nombre)
        elif PokemonEnemigo == arbok2:
            print(pokemon_escogido + ' VS ' + arbok2.nombre)
        elif PokemonEnemigo == raichu2:
            print(pokemon_escogido + ' VS ' + raichu2.nombre)
```

Comment: El código es difícil de comprender, debido a la indentación mal (al menos hay un `if` fuera de sitio, pero quizás más), y a los comentarios mezclados con instrucciones, como el "(aqui llamo...)" o los "etc". Por favor, arregla el indentado y pon al menos un `#` delante de los comentarios (e indentalos también como corresponda)

Comment: Necesitas una variable en la que guardes el pokemon que está luchando en ese momento, en tonces el if sería `if pokemon_seleccionado.hp <= 0`. Si simplemente miras el hp de TODOS los pokemon... obviamente siempre va a entrar mientras uno de ellos esté debilitado. Otra opción sería mantener la lista de pokemon peleando en una lista y cuando se debilitan sacarlos de la misma, pero eso es otra cosa ya

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos